# Sencha Visual Studio Plugin for Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, extjs, visual-studio-2013, plugins

I have just downloaded the trial version of Sencha IDE plugin for Visual Studio(2013).

After the installation, Sencha Project templates are available for for the C# project not for the Vb.net projects. Am I missing something here or Sencha IDE is supported only for C#?

Comment: The C# template is a default template provided by Sencha IDE. Syntax highlighting etc. should work from VB.net projects as well, just that there is no project template.

Comment: Understood now, Thanks Alexander for your help.